# With Gearman , can i check job failed how much times?

Tags: php, gearman

With Gearman , can i check job failed how much times ? 
example: if a job failed , i want it to repeat  . if job failed 5 times then delete it. I must use which function.

example: if i want queue up to download file from a server. If that server is down, then job can't be finished .

Comment: We Germans are such scrupulous workers, our jobs just **never fail!** Problem solved. Oh, wait...

Comment: example: if i want queue up to download file from a server. If that server is down, then job can't be finished .

Comment: @meotimidhia I'm just joking about the closeness of the words "German" and "Gearman". :) I understand what you mean in your question

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. You can't query how many times a job has failed.
However the information is there inside gearmand, but there is no API to access it yet.

I think the option you are looking for is

-j, --job-retries

This is an argument the gearmand server takes when starting. It specifies the number of times a job can be retried before being discarded. It is a global setting and cannot be configured to be different for different job types. It also cannot be set or changed from a gearman client.